# django cookiecutter extending base.html wipes out my web page

Tags: html, django, cookiecutter-django, cookiecutter

I am working on a project that I started in June 2017 with the cookiecutter I had just installed.  At the time, with respect to django, I was an absolute beginner.  (I am a bit more advanced by now, but just a bit.)

Cookiecutter put a base.html in the templates directory (one level above the app subdirectories).

For a list of model rows, I have a template that works all by itself, as follows:

```
{% if brand_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for brand in brand_list %}
        <li><a href="/brands/{{ brand.id }}/">{{ brand.cTitle }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No brands are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

But, if I put this at the top, I do not get the list::

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

What I get instead is the project root webpage, the one at /.

Is this base.html the problem, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

Your `base.html` mus have a pair of template tags like this:

```
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
```

The template that inherits from `base.html` populates the content between those tags:

So in your inherited template you put

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %} 

    {% if brand_list %}
        <ul>
        {% for brand in brand_list %}
            <li><a href="/brands/{{ brand.id }}/">{{ brand.cTitle }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>No brands are available.</p>
    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Excellent!  Adding the block content tags fixed the problem!  Thanks!