# Django templates inheritance looses original data

Tags: html, django, python-2.7

I'm learning django. I have a site with a data table that has the following html template:

```
{% load static %}
{% load table_tags %}

<link href="{% static 'table/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{% static 'table/js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'table/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>

<link href="{% static 'table/css/datatable.bootstrap.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{% static 'table/js/jquery.browser.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'table/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js' %}"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Impala query metrics</title>
   </head>
   <body>
    <div class="container" style="margin: 10px 10px 10px">
        <h1>Impala Query metrics</h1>
        <br />
        {% render_table people %}
    </div>

<a href="/logout">logout</a>

{% block content %} {% endblock %}



</body>
```

When i try to inherit with another template by adding

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

to the first line, it inherits with base.html but my original data table disappears. 
Any help on how to keep my original data table or pointing me to the right documentation would be appreciated.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47964402/django-cookiecutter-extending-base-html-wipes-out-my-web-page/47964721#47964721

Comment: @guillermochamorro thanks that did the trick